# How to call didSelectRowAt on every clicks on uiTableView in swift 3

Tags: uitableview, swift3

I have a situation to need only call **didSelectRowAt**.
when I click twice on a cell at first it calls **didSelectRowAt**, in second click it calls **didDeselectRowAt**. However, I need call **didSelectRowAt** in both clicks.
I don't want to use this solution:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // call select here
}
```

Because it is too complicated in my codes and it is not very clean & clear.
How can I prevent call **didDeselectRowAt** instead call **didSelectRowAt**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `didSelectRowAtIndexPah`, deselect the row

```
tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)
```